# Sum all rows in multiple columns, keeping the sum of each column separate in r

Tags: r

I have a df that looks something like this:

```
round1 <- c(1, 5, 3, 6)
round2 <- c(4, 5, 4, 6)
round3 <- c(1, 9, 8, 2)
round4 <- c(4, 8, 5, 3)
df = data.frame(round1, round2, round3, round4)
```

| round1 | round2 | round3 | round4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | 9 | 8 |
| 3 | 4 | 8 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 | 2 | 3 |

Each column is the score of a different round of a game (c1=round 1, c2=round 2, etc.). This matter because I plan to plot the average score of all players (rows) for each round over time.

I want to sum certain columns, say c1 and c3. I then want those sums (separate from each other) to be divided by the number of rows and placed in a new df:

```
sums <- c(3.75, 5)
```

| Sums |
| --- |
| 3.75 |
| 5 |

I have found several ways to do this manually (one column at a time), but I have 153 columns, so I do not want to do it manually.

Comment: `colMeans(df[c(1, 3)])`? A sum divided by number of observations is called "mean" or "average", rather "sum" btw

Comment: With `dplyr` you could use `summarize(across(c(round1, round3), mean))`

Comment: Oh my god, I'm such and idiot... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From David Arenburg:

```
colMeans(df[c(1, 3)])
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have David move their comment to an answer so you can give them the answer points